# Matching a single lines style with moderncv

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I'm pretty much brand new to LaTeX and and wanted to update my resume. I'm currently using moderncv banking style to do this. In moderncv there is a style called \cventry:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

And in my actual .tex document it looks like this:

```
\cventry{years active}{Job Position}{company}{location}{}{}
```

This makes the years active and the job position field temporarily in italics. I was wondering if I could somehow extract just those two fields without having the extra space above it created by \cventry?

Comment: Please provide a MWE as your code snippets do not compile in the moderncv style.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"?

Comment: what about company and location?